# Getting RepositoryNotFoundError in typeorm but I'm pretty sure they are registered

Tags: javascript, typescript, next.js, typeorm

I'm writing an app using Next.js + TypeORM and running in to an issue with the integration.

> RepositoryNotFoundError: No repository for "User" was found. Looks like this entity is not registered in current "default" connection?

From what I can tell I have everything configured correctly but continue to get this error. I've debugged and inspected the active connection and see the entities on `connection.options.entities` so they are registered. Really stumped by this one.

Repo: https://github.com/kyleect/bolt

Server:

```js
import "reflect-metadata";

import { createServer } from "http";
import { parse } from "url";
import { createConnection } from "typeorm";
import path from "path";
import next from "next";

import { Link } from "../entities/Link";
import { Post } from "../entities/Post";
import { User } from "../entities/User";

const dev = process.env.NODE_ENV !== "production";
const app = next({ dev });
const handle = app.getRequestHandler();

app
  .prepare()
  .then(() =>
    createConnection({
      type: "sqlite",
      database: "local.db",
      synchronize: true,
      logging: true,
      entities: [Link, Post, User],
    })
  )
  .then(() => {
    createServer((req, res) => {
      handle(req, res, parse(req.url, true));
    }).listen(3000, () => {
      console.log("> Ready on http://localhost:3000");
    });
  });
```

One of the endpoint handlers. There is a similar one for all of them and they all throw an error:

```js
const db = await getConnection();

const repo = db.getRepository(User);

const users = await repo.find();

res.json(users);
```

Entities:

```js
import {
  Entity,
  Column,
  PrimaryGeneratedColumn,
  OneToMany,
  CreateDateColumn,
  UpdateDateColumn,
  DeleteDateColumn,
} from "typeorm";
import { Post } from "./Post";

@Entity()
export class Link {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn("uuid")
  id: string;

  @CreateDateColumn()
  createdDate: Date;

  @UpdateDateColumn()
  updatedDate: Date;

  @DeleteDateColumn()
  deletedDate: Date;

  @Column({ type: "varchar" })
  url: string;

  @OneToMany((type) => Post, (post) => post.link)
  posts: Array<Post>;
}
```

```js
import {
  Entity,
  Column,
  PrimaryGeneratedColumn,
  ManyToOne,
  CreateDateColumn,
  UpdateDateColumn,
  DeleteDateColumn,
} from "typeorm";
import { User } from "./User";
import { Link } from "./Link";

@Entity()
export class Post {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn("uuid")
  id: string;

  @CreateDateColumn()
  createdDate: Date;

  @UpdateDateColumn()
  updatedDate: Date;

  @DeleteDateColumn()
  deletedDate: Date;

  @ManyToOne((type) => User, (user) => user.posts)
  user: User;

  @Column({ type: "varchar" })
  title: string;

  @Column({ type: "varchar" })
  body: string;

  @ManyToOne((type) => Link, (link) => link.posts)
  link: Link;
}
```

```js
import {
  Entity,
  Column,
  PrimaryGeneratedColumn,
  OneToMany,
  DeleteDateColumn,
  UpdateDateColumn,
  CreateDateColumn,
} from "typeorm";
import { Post } from "./Post";

@Entity()
export class User {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn("uuid")
  id: string;

  @CreateDateColumn()
  createdDate: Date;

  @UpdateDateColumn()
  updatedDate: Date;

  @DeleteDateColumn()
  deletedDate: Date;

  @Column({ type: "varchar" })
  username: string;

  @OneToMany((type) => Post, (post) => post.user)
  posts: Array<Post>;
}
```

Comment: I haven't found an answer to this so I'm leaving it open. I've switched to nestjs with typeorm and it works almost out of the box

Answer (score 4):

The reason it's not finding your entity is because the way your project is set up you are transpiling your server.ts to JavaScript and running `node ./dist/src/server.js`, however the api endpoint in users.ts is not being transpiled ahead of time but instead is being webpacked and loaded as an ESModule via your framework.

I'm not sure what is the right way to set this up, but I believe the fact that you've got two different ways to transpile the TypeScript is the cause of the problem. In the TypeORM internals, it compares the class you want, `User` to the class that has been given to TypeORM as an entity. This equality comparison will fail because of what I mentioned above. In JavaScript an equality comparison for an object actually looks at the memory location and that'll be different with two different node processes.

You have a couple options from here:

1. If you just want to see something, happen, change line 9 of `users.ts` to `const repo = db.getRepository('User');` - quote the entity name. TypeORM can also find entities by name. This works. I got a successful response when I did this.
2. Dig more into best practices in Vercel and TypeScript. Sorry, can't help you there!

I don't know if this is just a learning project or a million-dollar app. If it's the latter, I would definitely want to make sure the way Vercel handles your API endpoints is a best practice. I only know this framework by reputation, but looks to me like the approach there is suited for static content. I'm not sure why you wouldn't want your API to be transpiled along with your server.